# como establezco la cantidad de decimales que quiero mostrar de un double en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, double

Mi problema es que estoy usando `Math.Round` y me esta redondeando, lo que necesito es que solo me  muestre un solo decimal sin ser redondeado

Este es mi resulado normal

```
double rap = 0;
 rap = (11300 - 8508.54)* 0.015);
```

Que esto me da como resultado  `41.8719`

Esto es Cuando utilizo `Math.Round`

```
 double rap = 0;
     rap = Math.Round(11300 - 8508.54)* 0.015,1);
```

Me da como resultado `41.9`  y lo que necesito es que me de `41.8`

Esto es lo que necesito  `41.8` que ese sea mi resultado

Comment: No hace fala definir la cantidad de decimales cuando trabajas con un tipo de dato double, dejalo como lo calcula, al final cuando quieras mostrar el dato es que deberias definir la cantidad de decimal

Comment: hay algo raro con los numero que mencionas, dices al principio 41.8719, pero despues pasa a ser 4.9, es un valor de dos digitos o de uno ? digo es 41 o 4

Comment: ya modifique mi pregunta si es 41 no 4

Comment: @ Leandro Tuttini pero el tema que  necesito después dividir ese numero y si trae todos eso decimales me da otro resultado  , por ejemplo si me tocara dividir `41.8719 / 5 = 8.37` , pero si es `41.8 / 5 = 8.36`

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. Si lo que quieres es truncar un valor a un decimal, la respuesta de @GustavoCantero es correcta (`Math.Floor(rap*10)/10`). Si debes dividir `rap` entre 5, debes hacerlo despues del `Math.Floor`.

Comment: @ Pikoh es correcto ya me funciono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás haciendo un Round, por lo cual, 41.8719 redondeado a un decimal da 41.9.

Para "truncar" el valor a un decimal tal vez te convenga hacer esto:

```
double rap = 0;
rap = ((11300 - 8508.54)* 0.015);
rap = Math.Floor(rap * 10) / 10;
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Muy bien @Gustavo Cantero Pero que pasaría si agrego una división  `rap = ((11300 - 8508.54)* 0.015) / 5`    quisiera que  ese 41.8 se dividiera entre 5

Comment: La idea es que al número final lo multipliques por 10 y le saques los decimales, para que cuando lo vuelvas a dividir por 10 te quede con un sólo decimal.  No entiendo para qué dividirlo entre 5.

Comment: Ahí vi otra respuesta y vi que el resultado lo tenés que dividir por 5, entonces, podés hacer el cálculo que te pasé y después dividirlo por 5.  O sea, al final deberías hacer algo como rap = rap / 5.

Comment: yaaa Muchas gracias @ Gustavo Cantero

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función [Truncate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Redondea el decimal/double al entero más próximo cercano a cero.

Si usaramos `Math.Truncate(41.8719)` el resultado sería 41. Si te das cuenta, elimina el 8719 pues el entero mas próximo es 41.

Entonces, si queremos dos decimales, podemos multiplicar por 100 dicho valor para que no elimine esos decimales al aplicarle la función, y luego dividir dentro de 100 nuevamente para quedarnos con los dos decimales que queríamos.

Así:

```
rap = Math.Truncate(41.8719*100)/100;
```

Esto dará `Math.Truncate(4187.19)/100` = `4187/100` = `41.87`

Si quieres un decimal, multiplica y divide por 10, si quieres tres, por 1000, etc.